# How to profile/trace compiled c++ application

Tags: c++, debugging, window, trace

I have a Compiled c++ application which consists of the EXE and 1 DLL. When the application start the app crashes at when the loader reaches 30%. I have searched the machine up and down and could not find any type of log or anything in the event viewer. Is there some sort of application which could be used to trace which files the application is accessing or at least generate some sort of error log for this compiled application.

I have tried contacting the original vendor but they seem to have gone out of business. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Valgrind could possibly give you some insight on where/what its crashing on.

Comment: @MorphingDragon Thanx! Would uit be possible to debug remotely with Valgrind? As the application set is running on a windows platform

Comment: Ah its Windows. Unfortunately there's nothing strictly like Valgrind for windows. OllyDbg might be an option if you're comfortable with assembly debugging? http://www.ollydbg.de/

Comment: @MorphingDragon Welllllll.... Its always a good time to learn right :D

Comment: It's usually easier to learn on your own code. >.>

Comment: @MorphingDragon True but unfortunately I don't have that luxury. Anyway I will give this a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: I found this BTW, to trace application file access. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default

Answer (score 2):

You can try MS Dr. Watson.

- Click Start, and Run.
- Type drwtsn32, and execute it.

But its logs can be very verbose and hard to interpret.